# how to use drupal theme

Tags: 7

I try to use theme()

```
function test_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_custom_gallery' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'image_urls' => null,
      ),
      'template' => 'my-custom-gallery',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test') . '/templates',
    ),
  );
}


function test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $array = array('images' => array('test0' => 'test0', 'test1' => 'test1'));
  $output = theme('my_custom_gallery', $array);
  return $output;
}
```

And my-custom-gallery.tpl.php

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:300px;heoght:300px;">
<?php 
  print_r($images);
?>
</div>
```

But I not see the html from template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `test_theme()` function you set `image_urls` as the variable to the template. So print `$image_url` instead of `$images` in your template.

Try

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:300px;heoght:300px;">
<?php 
  print_r($image_urls);
?>
</div>
```

in my-custom-gallery.tpl.php

Comment: ok I will try, I also have some questions about why is need to write `image_urls` here and not use it in other place. But why red <div> not appear?

Comment: Add some static content in you template and confirm your template is taking for your form.

Comment: If I delete `<?php   print_r($image_urls); ?>` my red div appear, but still appear now an error with php code in .tpl or without `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/test/www/includes/form.inc on line 1080`

Comment: I think you are using drupal_get_form() in your menu call back. As you are trying to theme a form, pass `'render element' => 'form',` in you theme function.

Comment: like that ? `  return array(
    'my_custom_gallery' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'image_urls' => null,
      ),
      'template' => 'my-custom-gallery',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test') . '/templates',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );`

Comment: yes. Please try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44346/discussion-between-arun-and-mitch).

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear caches, so hook_theme() gets recognized.

Comment: I always clear caches when something is not done and have troubles and other strange things